# How do I export these function stored in const?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

const stories = [
  {
    title: 'React',
    url: 'https://react.js.org/',
    author: 'Jordan Walke',
    num_comments: 3,
    points: 4,
    objectId: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Redux',
    url: 'https://redux.js.org/',
    author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
    num_comments: 2,
    points: 5,
    objectId: 1,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My React</h1>

        <label htmlFor="search">Search: </label>
        <input id="search" type="text" />

      <hr />
      <list />
    </div>
  );
};

const List = () => {
  return stories.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item.objectId}>
        <span>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </span>
        <span>{item.author}</span>
        <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
        <span>{item.points}</span>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default App;
// export default App;
```

Comment: export const stories then 
import {stories} from "./'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export `List` component you could do someting like:

**App.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '../path/to/List.js'; //<-- here import List

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My React</h1>

        <label htmlFor="search">Search: </label>
        <input id="search" type="text" />

      <hr />
      <List />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Then I wuold suggest you to store `stories` in a separated file (maybe you need it in other components). So:

**constants.js file:**

```
export const stories = [
  {
    title: 'React',
    url: 'https://react.js.org/',
    author: 'Jordan Walke',
    num_comments: 3,
    points: 4,
    objectId: 0,
  },
  {
    title: 'Redux',
    url: 'https://redux.js.org/',
    author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
    num_comments: 2,
    points: 5,
    objectId: 1,
  },
];
```

Finally

**List.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { stories } from '../path/to/constants.js'; //<-- here import stories
    
const List = () => {
  return stories.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item.objectId}>
        <span>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </span>
        <span>{item.author}</span>
        <span>{item.num_comments}</span>
        <span>{item.points}</span>
      </div>
    );
  });
};
    
export default List; //<-- here export List
```